Staking contract
I am creating a staking contract were the rate of interest might change whenever through out the year and the user can stake and unstake any time. So I did draft a contract and I am able to successfully stake many times and from different address and in unstaking I am able to do it once but after which it keeps failing . I have gone through the calculations I don't think there is mistake there but not sure . I am testing it in remix. Am I missing something
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/IERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract StakingContract is ReentrancyGuard,Initializable, OwnableUpgradeable {
    IERC20Upgradeable public stakingToken;

    struct InterestRateChange {
        uint256 rate;
        uint256 startTime;
    }

    struct StakeInfo {
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 startTime;
        uint256 interestAccrued;
    }

    InterestRateChange[] public interestRateHistory;

    mapping(address => StakeInfo[]) public userStakes;

    event Staked(address indexed user, uint256 amount, uint256 timestamp);
    event Unstaked(address indexed user, uint256 amount, uint256 interest, uint256 timestamp);
    event Debug(string message, uint256 value);

    function initialize(IERC20Upgradeable _stakingToken) public initializer {
        __Ownable_init(msg.sender);
        stakingToken = _stakingToken;
        interestRateHistory.push(InterestRateChange({
            rate: 5, 
            startTime: block.timestamp
        }));
    }

    function setInterestRate(uint256 newRate) external onlyOwner {
        interestRateHistory.push(InterestRateChange({
            rate: newRate,
            startTime: block.timestamp
        }));
    }

    function stake(uint256 amount) external {
        require(amount > 0, "Cannot stake 0");
        require(stakingToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) > amount,"Staker has insufficent fund");
        stakingToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < userStakes[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            StakeInfo storage stakeInfo = userStakes[msg.sender][i];
            uint256 accrued = calculateInterest(stakeInfo);
            stakeInfo.interestAccrued += accrued;
            stakeInfo.startTime = block.timestamp; 
        }

        
        StakeInfo memory newStake = StakeInfo({
            amount: amount,
            startTime: block.timestamp,
            interestAccrued: 0
        });

        userStakes[msg.sender].push(newStake);

        emit Staked(msg.sender, amount, block.timestamp);
    }

    event DebugString(string message);
    event DebugUint(string message, uint256 value);

    function unstake(uint256 amount) external payable {
    require(amount > 0, "Cannot unstake 0");
    require(stakingToken.balanceOf(address(this))>amount,"Insufficient fund ");

    uint256 totalStaked = 0;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < userStakes[msg.sender].length; i++) {
        totalStaked += userStakes[msg.sender][i].amount;
    }
    
    emit Debug("Total Staked", totalStaked);
    
    require(totalStaked >= amount, "Insufficient staked amount");

    uint256 contractBalance = getContractBalance();
    emit Debug("Contract Balance", contractBalance);

    uint256 remainingAmount = amount;
    uint256 totalInterest = 0;
    uint256 totalPrincipal = 0;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < userStakes[msg.sender].length && remainingAmount > 0; i++) {
        StakeInfo storage stakeInfo = userStakes[msg.sender][i];
        uint256 stakeAmount = stakeInfo.amount;

        if (stakeAmount > remainingAmount) {
            uint256 accruedInterest = calculateInterest(stakeInfo) * remainingAmount / stakeAmount;
            stakeInfo.interestAccrued += accruedInterest;
            stakeInfo.amount -= remainingAmount;
            stakeInfo.startTime = block.timestamp; 
            totalInterest += accruedInterest;
            totalPrincipal += remainingAmount;

            remainingAmount = 0;
        } else {
            uint256 accruedInterest = calculateInterest(stakeInfo);
            stakeInfo.interestAccrued += accruedInterest;

            totalInterest += accruedInterest;
            totalPrincipal += stakeAmount;

            remainingAmount -= stakeAmount;

            // Remove the stake
            userStakes[msg.sender][i] = userStakes[msg.sender][userStakes[msg.sender].length - 1];
            userStakes[msg.sender].pop();
            i--; 
        }
    }

    uint256 totalAmount = totalPrincipal + totalInterest;
    emit Debug("Total Amount to Transfer", totalAmount);
    emit Debug("Remaining Amount", remainingAmount);

    require(contractBalance >= totalAmount, "Contract does not have enough balance");
    stakingToken.transfer(msg.sender, totalAmount);
    emit Unstaked(msg.sender, totalPrincipal, totalInterest, block.timestamp);
}



    function calculateInterest(StakeInfo memory stakeInfo) internal view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 totalInterest = 0;
        uint256 lastTime = stakeInfo.startTime;
        uint256 amount = stakeInfo.amount;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < interestRateHistory.length; i++) {
            InterestRateChange memory rateChange = interestRateHistory[i];
            if (rateChange.startTime > lastTime) {
                uint256 timePeriod = rateChange.startTime - lastTime;
                totalInterest += (amount * interestRateHistory[i - 1].rate * timePeriod) / (100 * 365 days);
                lastTime = rateChange.startTime;
            }
        }

        if (lastTime < block.timestamp) {
            uint256 timePeriod = block.timestamp - lastTime;
            totalInterest += (amount * interestRateHistory[interestRateHistory.length - 1].rate * timePeriod) / (100 * 365 days);
        }

        return totalInterest;
    }

    function getTotalFilecoins(address user) external view returns (uint256 totalAmount) {
        totalAmount = 0;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < userStakes[user].length; i++) {
            StakeInfo memory stakeInfo = userStakes[user][i];
            uint256 accruedInterest = calculateInterest(stakeInfo);
            totalAmount += stakeInfo.amount + stakeInfo.interestAccrued + accruedInterest;
        }
    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return stakingToken.balanceOf(address(this));
   }
}

Error :
transact to StakingContract.unstake errored: Error occurred: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.

